# Laravel model non-mandatory FK MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Simple question about Laravel. If I have a hierarchical table in mySQL (hierarchical as in it is a self-recursive table, which means one of its columns references another one of it's own columns

```
TABLE site_tree
INT page_id
INT parent_page_id (references site_tree.page_id)
```

What would be the model eloquent relationship type for this kind of a relation?

Question 2:

```
TABLE site_tree
INT page_id NULL

FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES page.page_id NON-MANDATORY

TABLE page
INT page_id
```

In this kind of a non-mandatory relationship, where the page_id in site_tree can be null, which kind of an eloquent relationship type would I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (I may not) here are your answers:

#### Question 1:

- `site_tree` belongsTo `site_tree` (parent relationship)
- `site_tree` hasMany `site_tree` (child relationship)

So they way I tend to model these is like this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

In fact I actually have a trait that any tree-like model can use, which has more generic versions of these methods, like this:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Tree
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(get_called_class(), $this->getForeignKey());
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(get_called_class(), $this->getForeignKey());
    }

    public function scopeTopLevel(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull($this->getForeignKey());
    }
}
```

Along with some extra handy methods like `isLeaf`, `getAncestors`, `getSiblings`, `getDescendants`, etc.

#### Question 2:

The same applies but now it's just a different table (the nullablility of the foreign key field really isn't that much of an issue *assuming I'm understanding your question correctly*) as Laravel will just return a null resource or empty Collection for the relationships. I'd say though that usually if you have this kind of relationship over two tables, you usually would enforce the relationship as anything that usually belongs to something else won't exist on its own, but hey your use-case is your use-case. Here are the classes:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use Tree; // the tree behaviour from above

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}

<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

In this case, I would enforce the `product` belongsTo `category` relationship, but `category_id` can be `null` in order to have a 'top level' category/categories.

Comment: No problem - if you mark this answer as the answer it'll let people know in the future, too.